# How to make a get() method to return enum type in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to return an enum type variable in Java?

For example:

```
public static class PhoneContact extends Contact
{
    private String phone;
    private enum Operator { VIP, ONE, TMOBILE };

    public PhoneContact(String date, String phone)
    {
        super(date);
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public Operator getOperator()
    {
        // return Operator;
    }
}
```

Doing this yields in the error statement: "Operator cannot be resolved to a variable". Can someone please provide an explanation for this phenomenon and how to be able to work around it in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is an _enum type variable_? Do you know what enums are? Do you know what return statements do?

Answer (score 4):

Your enum should not be private in the class. It should be on its own in its own Operator.java file. This way you can return it, and it will make sense to classes other than the PhoneContact class. Otherwise you'd have to make it public inside of and refer to it is PhoneContact.Operator.  e.g.,

```
public PhoneContact.Operator getOperator() {
    return operator;
}
```

---

But again better to make it a stand alone class:

Operator.java:

```
public enum Operator { 
   VIP, ONE, TMOBILE 
}
```

Do this, and this will now make sense to the compiler:

```
public Operator getOperator() {
    return operator;
}
```

Having said this, please let us know why your PhoneContact class is set up as an inner static class. Wouldn't it be better for PhoneContact to be in its own file as a non-static stand alone class?

---

**Edit**
And as per Sotirios Delimanolis's comment, you never create an Operator field. So

```
public class PhoneContact extends Contact {
    private String phone;
    private Operator operator;

    public PhoneContact(String date, String phone)
    {
        super(date);
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone()
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setOperator(Operator operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public Operator getOperator()
    {
        return operator;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: good point! Answer edited, and thanks!! I missed that completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you just need to do this:

```
public Operator getOperator()
{
    return Operator.VIP; //Or similar.
}
```